# Changing a class attribute based on currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, class, variables, time

So, I have a little code that doesn't work for some odd reason. It's task would be, to change the attribute `class` of an element with an id of `blogtxt` **IF** the `day` variable equals to 4, 5 or 6 *(Friday, Saturday, Sunday)*
I would also like the `hours` variable to get used at `day = 4 &&`.
Also, I'm sure the problem is not in the **IF** statement, because the code won't even execute `alert(currentTime)`

> **Q:** What is the problem with the code above?

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date()
var day = currentTime.getDay()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
alert(currentTime)
if (day = 4 && || day = 5 || day = 6) {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "friss");
    else document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bunch of errors, which JSLint detects:

`day = 4` should be `day == 4`.
There's an extraneous `&&` in the if clause.
You don't have a close brace for the then-clause, or an open brace for the else-clause.

Corrected code at http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7nRXG/

Comment: I doubt JSLint recommends `==`

Comment: It warns about `=` ("expected a conditional expression, but saw an assignment"), but doesn't recommend a specific replacement. Changing it to `==` quiets the warning -- JSLint can't tell when `===` would be more appropriate than `==` (unless you think it should assume `===` is always better).

Comment: I get `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.` whenever I use `==`

Comment: Maybe there are different versions of JSLint, or settings that control it. I was using the JSLint button at jsfiddle, it doesn't complain about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (day = 4 && || day = 5 || day = 6) {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "friss");
    else document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "");
}
```

should be:

```
if (day == 4 || day == 5 || day == 6) {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "friss");
} else {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here, which is why the code won't even execute:

```
if (day = 4 && || day = 5 || day = 6)
```

You cannot write `&& ||`, replace it with:

```
if (day === 4 || day === 5 || day === 6)
```

You also have a syntax error with the `else`, which should be:

```
if (day === 4 || day === 5 || day === 6) {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "friss");
} else {
    document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "");
}
```

Comment: And although JS doesn't really require it, it's good style to end all statements with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

give ; to finish the statement. // ";" is the statement terminator.
modify the code like this:

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var day = currentTime.getDay();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
alert(currentTime);
if (day = 4 && || day = 5 || day = 6){
 document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "friss");
else
 document.getElementById("blogtxt").setAttribute("class", "");}
</script>
```

hope this helps.

also you cannot use `&& ||`.. it is syntax error. replace it with `||`.

also curly braces(`{}`) are not finished properly in if-else statement.

and in if statement comparison operator is `==`  not `=`.